# Override background color in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-color, mozilla

I want to change background color in Firefox from white to gray (because my eyes get tired of white)

I try to change it this way:
Preferences -> Language and appearance -> Font -> Colors

But it does not work as expected on some complex web sites:

Original page:

[image]

Page with background color changed:

[image]

All I want to do is to darken the background, but not to change color of other elenments (links, text, scrollbars).

Can I do it in Firefox (or probably in other browser)? How [Preferences -> Language and appearance -> Font -> Colors] works in Firefox? Perhaps, there is some "override css" for the entire browser?

Comment: I think there are plugns for executing custom js in the browser so you could just modify the body or something like that. Maybe: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ this is something for you?

Comment: F. Müller : thanks, but I don't want to do it through JS. I do not have any experience with JS and don't want to get this experience. I only want to change BG color of the page!